# Spark Predicate pushdown not working on date

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am just reading a parquet file and adding a filter to match all records that falls in date - here 2021-04-03. The column shoudn't be null and it should be on the date given.

Input table

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|      lat|        lng|       eventDTLocal|
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|34.269788| -98.239543|2021-04-03 19:18:58|
|29.780977| -95.749744|2021-04-03 19:33:24|
|48.150173|-122.191903|2021-04-03 17:25:00|
|40.652889| -74.185461|2021-04-03 20:27:55|
|41.747148| -87.799557|2021-04-03 19:52:39|
+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I have tried casting the column to date, used substring_index function for matching but I am just not able to get it in the pushed filters.

Following are the code I tried :

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet("/Users/aadhithyahari/Downloads/awsfiles/part-00000-bfccec4c-7939-4f85-8fa9-5f1cb34f843a.c000.snappy.parquet") \
        .select( 'lat', 'lng', 'eventDTLocal').filter("TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`eventDTLocal`, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS TIMESTAMP),'yyyy-MM-dd') == CAST('2021-04-03' AS DATE)").explain(extended=True)
```

The filters are listed only In Data Filters and not anywhere else. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all filters can be pushed down. In general most filters that contain function calls like `substring` or `unix_timestamp` cannot be pushed down. The complete logic which filters will be pushed down is implemented in [DataSourceStrategy](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSourceStrategy.scala).

A way to work around this limitation in this case would be to store the values of `eventDTLocal` as unix timestamps instead of strings in the parquet file and then filter on the specific milliseconds.

```python
#create some test data
data = [(52.5151923, 13.3824107, 1618760421000), 
        (1.0, 1.0, 1)]
spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['lat', 'lng', 'eventDTLocal']) \
    .write.mode("overwrite").parquet("dataWithUnixTime")

#get the first and last millisecond of the day
#the timezone has probably to be adjusted
from datetime import datetime, timezone
dt = datetime(2021, 4, 18)
start = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000
end = start + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - 1

#run the query
df = spark.read.parquet("dataWithUnixTime") \
    .filter(f"eventDTLocal >= {start} and eventDTLocal <= {end}")
```

The physical plan of `df`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [lat#9, lng#10, eventDTLocal#11L]
+- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(eventDTLocal#11L) AND (eventDTLocal#11L >= 1618704000000)) AND (eventDTLocal#11L <= 1618790399999))
   +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
      +- FileScan parquet [lat#9,lng#10,eventDTLocal#11L] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(eventDTLocal#11L), (eventDTLocal#11L >= 1618704000000), (eventDTLocal#11L <= 161879039..., Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/home/werner/Java/pyspark3/dataWithUnixTime], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(eventDTLocal), GreaterThanOrEqual(eventDTLocal,1618704000000), LessThanOrEqual(eventDT..., ReadSchema: struct<lat:double,lng:double,eventDTLocal:bigint>
```

now contains the pushed filters `GreaterThanOrEqual` and `LessThanOrEqual` for the date column.